# Problems Upgrading Facebook SDK from 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

I have a project that utilizes the Facebook SDK 3.0, which I built it in Xcode 4.3.2.  I now must update the project to Xcode 4.5 which also requires me to update the Facebook SDK to 3.1.  When I run the project in Xcode 4.5 (without changing anything), it builds and I can connect to Facebook, but of course when I try to run it on my iPhone with OS 6, I get a build failed message. SO, I went through all the tutorials on the FB developer's site, and changed the code that they highlighted, BUT when I put the new code in, I get all kinds of errors. Xcode does not know what I am talking about anymore. For example, I changed the previous general permissions code to the below "read" permissions code:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
        allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                FBSessionState state,
                                    NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                            state:state
                                            error:error];
                                     }];
}
```

and I get the error, "no known class method for selector..."

Its worth noting that I opened a new Xcode project and rehearsed entering the facebook SDK and all of the code from scratch and it worked perfectly.  So my question is, how do I just UPDATE my already existing app to use the new SDK!!?? Help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered my own question, the SDK was just the old version. Thought I updated it, but apparently not!

Comment: I'm having the same problem... How can I be sure that I'm using the new version of the SDK??

Comment: You have to go to https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ and download the SDK, the newest version is the one they have on this site... it came out in early October of 2012. If you are using an old SDK, you will get error messages similar to the ones I had because they have changed some of the methods.